# Better way to process dmidecode data using awk/sed

Tags: awk

I run

```bash
dmidecode -t 4 | awk '/Signature/,/L1 Cache Handle/' |
                   grep -e 'Signature' -e 'L1 Cache Handle' |
                   awk -v Model="$4" '{
                   if ($4 == "Model")
                      print $5 " " $7;
                   else if ($1 == "L1")
                      print " " $4}' >> data
```

The contents of 'data' on my system is :

```
49, 0
 0x002E
```

Essentially, 'data' corresponds to :
Signature: Family 23, Model 49, Stepping 0
L1 Cache Handle: 0x002E
(Model # and L1 cache handle)

Looking for a better/efficient way to do the above operation.  Thanks.

Comment: `if ($4 == "Model")` -- this is testing the 4th field is the literal string "Model", not the value of the `Model` _variable_ you're specifying with the `-v` value.

Comment: Show the complete output of the dmidecode command.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to properly format your question.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
dmidecode -t 4 | sed -nE '/Signature|L1 Cache Handle/{s/.*Model ([0-9]+), Stepping ([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/p;s/.*L1 Cache Handle: ([0-9A-Za-z])/\1/p}' | xargs
```

- The `sed` command extracts the values for `Model`, `Stepping` and
  `L1 Cache Handle:`.
- The final `xargs` merges two lines into one.

Comment: @glenn the complete output of dmidecode is:

bash-3.2# dmidecode -t 4
...
Handle 0x0031, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
  ...
        Signature: Family 23, Model 49, Stepping 0
        Flags:
                FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
...                HTT (Multi-threading)
        Version: AMD EPYC 7232P 8-Core Processor
        Voltage: 1.1 V
        External Clock: 100 MHz
        Max Speed: 4100 MHz
        Current Speed: 3100 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: Socket SP3
        L1 Cache Handle: 0x002E
...

Comment: You are putting the comment in the wrong place as I'm not glenn jackman.
It is recommended to post the output of the dmidecode command in your
question, not as a comment to be properly formatted including the newline
characters. BTW I'm waiting for your feedback if my answer works. BR.